# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1), Ajax render in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm really new at working with AJAX.  I'm trying to make a little status update type thing, similar to facebook or twitter.  You post a status and it adds it to the list below you, and clears out the edit box.

The post is being added to the database just fine.  The problem is the list of recent status messages is not being redrawn.  I'm getting an error, ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)).

I have tried to rewrite the js.erb several ways and it always has the error.  Some assistance would be appreciated.

The Controller **posts#create**

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id


    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        @posts = Post.all
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.js render  #@posts } # { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The Partial **_inline.html.erb** /posts/inline

```
<div class="large-12 columns" id="inline_posts">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-10 columns left"><%= post.content %></div>
    <div class="large-2 columns right"><%= link_to 'Remove', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'tiny button' %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

The Javascript **create.js.erb**

```
$("#inline_posts").html("<%= escape_javascript("render partial: 'posts/inline', posts: @posts ") %>")
```

Comment: Have you tried <%= render partial: "form", locals: {zone: @zone} %>  This is from the documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: I tried render partial: "posts/inline", locals: {posts: @posts}, which i assume is the same as that

Comment: I see no difference, so yes the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if i change

```
format.js render
```

to

```
format.js
```

it works fine.

Sorry for the bother